# How to fill out a row of N/A with values from rows with values matching on a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have missing records that I need to carry from one row to another joined by a single column.

Here's an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'animal':['horse','cat','cat','dog'],
                   'type':['big','small',np.nan,'medium'],
                   'rating':[1,2,np.nan,2]})

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  animal  rating    type
0  horse       1     big
1    cat       2   small
2    cat     NaN     NaN
3    dog       2  medium
```

Desired output:

```
  animal  rating    type
0  horse       1     big
1    cat       2   small
2    cat       2   small
3    dog       2  medium
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your rows aren't always lined up correctly for a ffill(), you can accomplish the same result by splitting your dataframes in a good and bad set, fixing the bad set and recombining. For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'animal':['horse','cat','cat','dog'],
                   'type':['big','small',np.nan,'medium'],
                   'rating':[1,2,np.nan,2]})
df1.set_index('animal',inplace=True)
good_df1 = df1[~df1.isnull().any(axis=1)]
bad_df1 = df1[df1.isnull().any(axis=1)]
final = pd.concat([good_df1, bad_df1.fillna(good_df1)]).reset_index()
```

Which gives:

```
  animal  rating    type
0  horse     1.0     big
1    cat     2.0   small
2    dog     2.0  medium
3    cat     2.0   small
```

To only fill certain columns, replace the last line with:

```
fill_cols = ['rating']
final = pd.concat([good_df1, bad_df1[fill_cols].fillna(good_df1[fill_cols])]).reset_index()
```

Or:

```
fill_cols = list(df1.columns)
fill_cols.remove('type')
final = pd.concat([good_df1, bad_df1[fill_cols].fillna(good_df1[fill_cols])]).reset_index()
```

Alternatively if your dataset allows you could use ffill() as mentioned but with an extra sort step to ensure your good data comes first:

```
df1.sort_values(['animal','rating','type']).fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to ignore certain columns like "type"?

Comment: Sure , added two ways, white listing or black list to the above